# Trying to write PL / SQL that counts backwards based on user input

Tags: oracle, plsql

First time trying to write PL/SQL

I found this simple question but I am stuck on it

Take any number N and write a procedure such that if N = 10, it should print

10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.

If N is negative, give an error message.

Any idea on how to approach this ?

Comment: Sorry, this site is not a free homework preparation service. It is for specific questions about the code **you** write. What did **you** try? Where did you run into problems?

Comment: @Danny Nguyen: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are going to want a loop. See here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/for_loop.php. That should get you started. In the mean time, I am voting to close your question because it is too broad for this site. Study that link and loop syntax and make some attempts to solve it. After that, if you have some specific code or aspect of it that is causing you problems come back with that and we will gladly help you out.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST AS
    x NUMBER := 10;

BEGIN
    if x < 0
    then
        dbms_output.put_line('error');
    else
        FOR y IN REVERSE 1..x LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(y);
        END LOOP;
    end if;
END TEST;
```

Comment: was this the answer to your problem, or is this an elaboration on what was not working before?